# VLC 3.0.4 fullscreen bug (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: unity, launcher, vlc

Ever since the last VLC update, I have this problem. I am using Ubuntu 18.04. In fullscreen, besides the video, VLC also shows Unity launcher (side bar) and the Ubuntu top bar (see the screenshot).

If I left click on the video, the bars disappear. But when I change the audio volume or pause the video, or move the mouse cursor, they reappear.

I have tried uninstalling VLC and installing it again, but the problem remains.

My specs are:

HP G5 255 (laptop)
15,6 inch 1080p display
AMD A6-7310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics × 4 (1 GB allocated to iGPU)
Gallium 0.4 on AMD MULLINS (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.15.0-39-generic, LLVM 6.0.0), Mesa 18.0.5
12 GB DDR3L 1600 MHz (4 + 8 GB)
Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit, Unity 7

Screenshot: [image: VLC3.0.4 fullscreen bug]

"Problem between Qt and Unity"?
https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=147281&sid=350ff85f4dbb4339e3d100d3667d193d

Comment: Yes, installed it maually (right after installing Ubuntu). I had no problems with this since I have installed Ubuntu 18.04. It only happened when VLC was updated to version 3.0.4.

Comment: Well, the comment from pomsky(?) was deleted? He was asking me if I have installed Unity manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VLC 3.0.4 security risks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153346/vlc-3-0-4-security-risks)