# VLC Security Flaw with Potential for RCE! Should Ubuntu Users Worry?

Tags: security, vlc, lts, hacking

A [security flaw, potentially serious](https://gizmodo.com/you-might-want-to-uninstall-vlc-immediately-1836641101) has been found in VLC:

> The vulnerability allows for RCE (remote code execution) which
>   potentially allows bad actors attackers to install, modify, or run
>   software without authorization, and could also be used to disclose
>   files on the host system. Translation: VLC’s security hole could allow
>   hackers to hijack your computer and see your files.

However, it might not be *that* bad:

> **[Update 8:35 AM]** Based on a tweet by VideoLAN, VLC may not be as
>   vulnerable as it initially appeared. VideoLAN says the “security
>   issue” in VLC was caused by a third-party library called Libebml that
>   was fixed 16 months ago, and that Mitre’s claim was based on a
>   previous (and outdated) version of VLC.

Either way this sounds pretty intense... Should I be immediately uninstalling VLC? How vulnerable is Ubuntu LTS vs Current?

Comment: No. If VideoLan say it's been patched then it's been patched. I'm not worried anyway and I often use SMPlayer which in some respects I find plays videos and DVDs better than VLC.

Comment: This genre of question pops up rather often. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153346/ubuntu-security-risk-due-to-default-vlc-3-0-4-package?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an [Ubuntu Security Notice issued](https://usn.ubuntu.com/4073-1/) addressing the matter and indicating that a patch was available concerning the flaw in the library that had the vulnerability.  Versions impacted were 16.04 and 18.04.  The updated package was posted by the security team to the package archive the day after this question was originally posted.

In short, you should simply let Update Manager run as normal rather than uninstall VLC.

A general FAQ concerning the Ubuntu Security Team [is available](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#Official%20Support) for review.